# detecting inpage image links and displaying them with jQuery

Tags: jquery

What would be the best way to force jQuery to detect if an element in post-content class is an image and then display that image in-page. I have done this with BBCode many times, but want to make it easier for users. By just allowing them to paste the link and the system goes from there own.

```
            $comments = $posts_row['post_content'];

            $m = preg_match_all( "/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/", $comment, $match);

            if ($m) {
                 $links = $match[0];
                 foreach($links as $link) {
                 $extension = strtolower(trim(@end(explode(".",$link))));
                 switch($extension) {
                 case 'gif':
                 case 'png':
                 case 'jpg':
                 case 'jpeg':
                   $comment = str_replace($link, '<img src="'.$link.'">', $comment);       
                 break;
                 default:
                 $comment = str_replace($link, '<a rel="nofollow" href="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a>', $comment);
                 break;
                 }
              }
            }
```

Comment: Before asking another question, you should go back and choose answers for the other _6_ you have not closed yet.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I have PHP code but wanna transition that into jQuery. I don't click Answered most of the time :D, plus I am not on StackOverflow as much as I used to be

Comment: @Cl': Stackoverflow is a good system, you ask for help, you get help and the polite thing is to accept an answer if it helped you solve your issue. It's doesn't matter if you are only on stackoverflow ones a year or every day. Clicking accept on an answer takes little time.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I agree with you, and I agree that it was my fault for not doing that. However I have now accepted those answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.post-content').find('img').show()
```

Comment: nope, nothing changes. To me this code looks like it finds image element and just displays it. But my image elements are actual image links with .jpg, .png, .jpeg or .gif extensions. I am trying to see if jQuery can detect that part and turn the URL into SRC attribute and bind that to the post-content class

Comment: @Cl' So you should use ajax, can you post the rendered markup?

Comment: there is no markup, I was just thinking if I could use "$('.post-content').append("<img src="' + url + '" />");" but that aint going to work. The problem lies in the detection part. So jQuery has to check for anything that looks like a link in plain text that was spitted out from MySQL table. And then convert that plain text link into image attribute on the page

Comment: @Cl' That should work, there is a syntax error in your code, try this http://jsfiddle.net/tpQDJ/

Comment: @Cl' Do you mean from a paragraph texts? This is possible but very complex.

Comment: yes, from Paragraph I was imagining it would be hard, its fairly easy to do with PHP so I am guessing I will stick with PHP then untill I can see what can be done with jQuery